# MapReduce gives odd result when count == 1

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

Stack: MongoDB 2.6.5, Mongoid 3.1.6, Ruby 2.1.1

I'm using Mongoid to do some MongoDB Map/Reduce stuff.

Here's the setup:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :given_bonuses, class_name: 'Bonus', inverse_of: :giver
  has_many :received_bonuses, class_name: 'Bonus', inverse_of: :receiver
end

class Bonus
  include Mongoid::Document


  belongs_to :giver, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :given_bonuses
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :received_bonuses
end
```

I'm using the following Map/Reduce code:

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    emit(this.receiver_id, this.giver_id)
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    var result = {};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      if(! result[value]) {
        result[value] = 0;
      }
      result[value] += 1;
    });
    return result;
  }
}

Bonus.all.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: 1)
```

Let's say I have two or more bonus documents:

```
> Bonus.count
 => 2
> Bonus.all.to_a
 => [#<Bonus _id: 547612a21dbe8b7859000071, giver_id: "547612441dbe8bf35b000005", receiver_id: "547612531dbe8b4a7200006a">, #<Bonus _id: 547612a21dbe8b78590000f9, giver_id: "547612441dbe8bf35b000005", receiver_id: "547612531dbe8b4a7200006a">]
```

Then the Map/Reduce result is:

```
 => [{"_id"=>"547612531dbe8b4a7200006a", "value"=>{"ObjectId(\"547612441dbe8bf35b000005\")"=>2.0}}]
```

Notice that the `value` key points to a hash of the form `{"ObjectID" => Number}`. This is as it should be.

Now let's say I have *only* one bonus document:

```
> Bonus.count
 => 1
> Bonus.first
 => #<Bonus _id: 547612a21dbe8b7859000071, giver_id: "547612441dbe8bf35b000005", receiver_id: "547612531dbe8b4a7200006a">
```

Then the Map/Reduce result is:

```
 => [{"_id"=>"547612531dbe8b4a7200006a", "value"=>"547612441dbe8bf35b000005"}]
```

Notice that the schema of the result has changed. It should be:

```
 => [{"_id"=>"547612531dbe8b4a7200006a", "value"=>{"ObjectId(\"547612441dbe8bf35b000005\")"=>1.0}}]
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Not sure if it's a mongoid issue, but I've filed an issue with them: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3869

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-reduce-cmd):

> MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a
>   single value. The values argument is an array whose elements are the
>   value objects that are “mapped” to the key.

In the first case the key `this.receiver_id`, has two documents in its group and hence the reduce function is invoked for that key.

In the second case when your `emitted` key has only **one** record in its group, the reduce function **won't** be called at all.

So the value(`this.giver_id`) that you emit for the key, is being displayed as emitted without being reduced, there is no need for it to be reduced further.

Comment: Is there a way to force MongoDB to call the `reduce`? It adds a lot of complexity if I have to handle two different result schemas.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, ideally there would be nothing to reduce for a group with one document. The `Reduce` should bot be treated for output formatting.

Comment: Right, but I'm doing the mapreduce with a million+ documents. Whenever there happens to be just one match for a particular receiver, the result schema is different than 2+ matches. Which means I have to write code that checks the schema of each result instead of just knowing the schema will be the same for all results. There's got to be a more sensible. way.